# How to add search/filter method in v-data-table?

Tags: typescript, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I made search and filter function in v-data-tabel using by filter method and includes method in Javascript.
but it didn't work.
I have checked develop tool but error didn't occur.
I thought computed method was better in my case, so
I tried to made getter method instead of computed.
Does some know what kind of method is better in that case?

Does anyone help me?

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <h2>{{ message }}</h2>
        <v-text-field type="text" v-model="search"></v-text-field>
        <v-data-table
         dense
         :headers="header"
         :items="items"
         class="elevation-1"
         >
         <template v-slot:items="{ search_users}">
             <tbody>
                 <tr v-for="item in search_users" :key="item.email">
                     <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                     <td>{{item.email}}</td>
                     <td>{{item.website}}</td>
                 </tr>
             </tbody>
         </template>
        </v-data-table>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {Component, Vue} from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
import axios from 'axios'

@Component({})
export default class extends Vue{
    message:string='Search/Filter In Table'
    search:string=''
    header = [
        {text:'name',value:'name'},
        {text:'email',value:'email'},
        {text:'website',value:'website'}
    ]
    items:any=[]
    get search_users(){
        return this.items.fileter((item:any)=>{
            return item.name.includes(this.search)
        })
    }
    async mounted(){
        const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
        this.items = response.data.map((item:any)=>({
            name:item.name,
            email:item.email,
            website:item.website
        }));
    }
    
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data for the table is provided through its `items` prop. So if you want the table to show your filtered list, provide that value instead. The items slot is meant to control display for a single item and can be omitted if you use the default rendering.

Example:

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="header"
    :items="search_users"
  ></v-data-table>
</template>
```

Comment: Than you for your answer!! I really appreciate it!! Thanks!